# No matching method found: create for class com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigQueryImpl

Tags: clojure, google-bigquery

I'm currently working in a Backend written in Clojure. In short, I'm trying to store into BigQuery some data, but when I try to create a dataset the error reported in the title appears. Here some code:

- Method to create the service:

```
(defn create-service []
  (.getService (BigQueryOptions/getDefaultInstance)))
```

- Method to create the dataset:

```
(defn create-dataset [dataset-name]
      "Given a name, it creates a dataset in BigQuery"
       (println "creating a dataset called: " dataset-name)
       (def bigquery (create-service))
       (def dataset-info (.build (DatasetInfo/newBuilder dataset-name)))
       (.create bigquery dataset-info)
  )
```

I also tried with other method in BigQueryImpl, downgraded the library, but the result is the same.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: create for class com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl, compiling:(main.clj:172:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: create for class com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl, compiling:(main.clj:172:24)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3657)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3651)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7474)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7541)
        at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:406)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:451)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
        at clojure.core$compile$fn__5682.invoke(core.clj:5903)
        at clojure.core$compile.invokeStatic(core.clj:5903)
        at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5895)
        at user$eval20$fn__29.invoke(form-init4156994521630280254.clj:1)
        at user$eval20.invokeStatic(form-init4156994521630280254.clj:1)
        at user$eval20.invoke(form-init4156994521630280254.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: create for class com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:53)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
        at gc_webapp.persistence.gcs$create_dataset.invokeStatic(gcs.clj:177)
        at gc_webapp.persistence.gcs$create_dataset.invoke(gcs.clj:168)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3652)
        ... 35 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm a beginner with Clojure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation of the BigQuery interface, you see that the `create` method actually has Java's idea of a variadic signature:

```
Dataset     create(DatasetInfo datasetInfo, BigQuery.DatasetOption... options)
```

This is actually (at the JVM level) another required parameter which is auto-filled by the Java *language* at the call site.  In Clojure, you have to provide it explicitly to match the signature:

```
(.create bigquery dataset-info (into-array BigQuery$DatasetOption []))
```

Side note: `def` always creates global definitions.  It is almost always wrong to use it anywhere that is not top level.  Use `let` instead, and standard formatting:

```
(defn create-dataset [dataset-name]
  "Given a name, it creates a dataset in BigQuery"
  (println "creating a dataset called: " dataset-name)
  (let [bigquery (create-service)
        dataset-info (.build (DatasetInfo/newBuilder dataset-name))]
    (.create bigquery dataset-info (into-array BigQuery$DatasetOption [])))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation. However now when I call DatasetOption from `BigQuery/DatasetOption` since DatasetOption is a static class in BigQuery, I get `Unable to find static field: DatasetOption in interface com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery`

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Referring to static inner classes is done with their real name, here `BigQuery$DatasetOption`.  I'll edit.